# IP Switch between 2 domain controllers

Tags: domain-name-system, active-directory, ip, domain-controller

I have several domain controllers in my domain and I need to switch the IP between 2 of them ( one with Windows Server 2k8 R2 and one with Windows Server 2k12 R2 )

I did the following steps until now:

```
netdom computername xxx.contoso.com /add:xxy.contoso.com
netdom computername xxx.contoso.com /makeprimary:xxy.contoso.com
netdom comnputername xxx.contoso.com /verify
```

After this i rebooted the DC and deleted the old name.

```
netdom computername xxy.contoso.com /remove:xxx.contoso.com
```

After that I made the changes on the second DC:

```
netdom computername yyy.contoso.com /add:xxx.contoso.com
netdom computername yyy.contoso.com /makeprimary:xxx.contoso.com
netdom comnputername yyy.contoso.com /verify
```

Basically the same steps to switch ip's between them. The problem is now that both of them have name resolution problems. When i perform **dcdiag /fix** it recognizes the old name on both of them ( NOTE: both servers are virtual and i switched their IP's before starting the renaming operation ) and same problem in ADUC ( i can see xxx.contoso.com and xxy.contoso.com ) but when i connect to them both their hostnames are the corect ones that i changed.

Any advices on some troubleshooting ?

Thank you.

Comment: Why did you use netdom? You weren't renaming them, you were changing their ip addresses. The only thing that should have changed from an AD perspective is the respective A record for each DC in DNS. Most articles related to this recommend running dcdiag/fix to make sure the SRV records are registered correctly after changing the ip address of a DC but I don't see this as being necessary. The SRV records are registered for the DC names, not their ip addresses, so making sure the A record for each DC is registered correctly is all that should be needed. Where did you get the idea to run netdom?

Answer (score 0):

All you needed to do was change the IP and register DNS, use a 3rd IP as an intermediary

```
ipconfig /registerdns
```

since you've already changed IPs, go in DNS, the A Records for your two servers and then rerun the above command.